# Is this a car part?

Tags: part-identification

The white object in the photo was found in a place where a car was parked.

Is this a car part?

In case it would help, the parking place was in a country guesthouse, so maybe it's a piece from other machine.[image: photo of unknown item]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Looks like some sort of sifter or filter to me.  The cog (gear) with the hole in the center indicates that it might be designed to spin along the z-axis.  The edges, on the other hand, look more like they lock in place.  Can you spin the center?  Does it smell of anything?

Comment: Doesn't look like any car part I've ever seen.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket good points but it is not in my possession, countryhouse owner sent my the photo after we left the place. I also think that it could be a kind water pump filter, or maybe a ventilation grill in a motor.

Comment: My best guess is a grain sifter or a honey filter, but I'm really not sure without a closer look.

Answer (score 5):

The piece is a washer fluid tank filter from Skoda Scala. It should be placed by error during fabrication process somewhere inside because my car has its own piece in correct place.[image]

After almost a year and a half, mystery solved.